# I'd like to show/hide button based on URL loaded in webview

Tags: android, url, button, conditional-statements, hide

I've got a button that I've overlaid in my webView that I have going to a particular "home URL" when clicked. It shows up over each page loaded in my webview, but I need to make it invisible when the actual home url is loaded. Obviously, there's no need for a "main menu" type button to appear when you're already on the main menu. Here's my current code for my conditional:

```
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)
{
    if (url.equals("http://"URL.GOES.HERE"))
    {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }           
}
```

My button is created this way:

```
 webview.loadUrl("http://URL.GOES.HERE");
   Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
   button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Can anyone help? BTW, URLs are dummied out.

Comment: Could you identify the question, your source code here looks like a good start.

Comment: My question is I need to hide the button for one particular URL and show it for any other URLs. For example: IF (URL=A), THEN hide button, ELSE show button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the onPageFinished()?

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String url){
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work with the following method:

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new Callback()); //declare this subclass in onCreate


    private static class Callback extends WebViewClient {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.equals("https://google.com" // your url)) {
                    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 } else {
                    fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 }
            }
        }
```